# Express not matching route with wildcard?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am having url

```
localhost:3001/item/id?5
```

But express not matching this route with router

```
app.get('/item/id?:id')
```

Its matching route with

```
app.get('/item/id/:id').
```

But how to match localhost:3001/item/id?5 this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything after the `?` in the URL is a query parameter. You don't match them with wildcards in the routes, instead you can retrieve them with

```
app.get('/user/:id?', function userIdHandler(req, res) {
  var id = req.query.id;
});
```

See [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) for additional info.